# append related subselect options once

Tags: php, jquery, append

how can i append select options once of subselect menu after i change the main select

the problem is that the the options are added eveytime i change the select option

how can i make every main select option to only select it's related options only one time

html&php:

```
  <?php
    $get_tables=$this->db->query("select * from floor_plan where fp_name='bellevue' and status='available' order by abs(t_id)");
    ?>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="qtn">Choose Table:</label>
    <select name="parent_table" id="table_all_numbers" class="form-control">
    <?php
    while($each_row=$get_tables->fetch_assoc()){

            ?>
        <option rel="<?php echo $each_row['ava_seats']; ?>" class="<?php echo $each_row['t_name']; ?>" value="<?php echo $each_row['t_id']; ?>">#<?php echo $each_row['t_id']; ?> &nbsp;<?php if($each_row['t_name']=='vip'){echo   '$'.$each_row['price']."/Table";}else{echo '$'.$each_row['price']."/Seat";} ?></option> 
            <?php

    }
    ?>
    </select>
   </div>
```

jquery:

```
var $items = $('select[name=parent_table]');
//quantity
$items.change(function(){
    var $this=$(this).find(':selected'),
    rel=$this.attr('rel');

   for(i=0;i<=rel;i++){

          $("#qtn").show();
          $("<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>").appendTo('#qtn');
   }

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
$items.change(function(){
  var $this=$(this).find(':selected'),
    rel=$this.attr('rel');

  $('#table_all_numbers').html('');
  for(i=0;i<=rel;i++){
    $('#qtn')
      .append($('<option></option>')
      .attr("value", i)
      .text(i)); 
  }
  $("#qtn").show();
});
```

Comment: still the same problem,the subselect options are added after every change to the main select options

Comment: Hope ur requirement is to remove the options in the select tag and add the new option depending on the select change. if so, i edited the answer. plz check..

Comment: this edited answer also not solve the problem:
i'll discuss the procedure:

1-first i'll choose any option from the main menu

2-second: a new options in subselect menu will appear

3-if i changed the previous option from the main menu, related options in subselect menu will appear and the old one disappear.....

look to this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/bY5LF/

i want something like that,but using for loop to fetch data from db

Comment: thanks sathya,i edited your old answer and i added a line in it's top to remove any old options,and the code work good now,appreciated my bro....